# Change month that is in numbers to month like 1 to January, 2 to Febuary, etc

Tags: r, date

I want to change digits to month name in r, how can I do that? for example "1" change it to "january". the dataset is big, so i just run the first 6.

```
  X                          place ZONE TYPE.OF.CRIME year month WEEK day HOUR
1 1 KIEPIES CLUB                     NA ARMED ROBBERY 2011     1    1   1   23
2 2 AUSSPANNPLATZ                    14 ARMED ROBBERY 2011     1    1   3   10
3 3 UNAM BUSHES                      16 ARMED ROBBERY 2011     1    1   7   14
4 4 TOTAL SERV. STATION, KHOMASDAL    9 ARMED ROBBERY 2011     1    1   8   21
5 5 WOODPALM STR 625                 11 ARMED ROBBERY 2011     1    2  15 <NA>
6 6 C KANDOVAZU STR                   5   ASSAULT GBH 2011     1    1   3   14
```

Comment: Try `month.name[1]`

Comment: Try `month.name[data$X]`.